How to marshall ? And ZonedDateTime in protostream 4.4.3java8
I have
class P{
@ProtoField(number=1, CollectionImplementation=ArrayList.class)
 List<? extends Account> accounts;
@ProtoField(number=2)
ZonedDateTime fromDate;
@ProtoFactory
P(List<? extends Account> accounts, ZonedDateTime fromDate) {
this.accounts=accounts;
this.fromDate=fromDate;
}

}
And Proto schema builder as
@AutoProtoBuilder(
basePackages="com.domain",
schemaFileName="abc.proto",
schemaFilePath="proto/",
schemaPackageName="pkg_abc")
Public interface ProtoInitializer extends GeneratedSchema {
}

accounts can be
SavingAccount extends Account{
name_sa;
}
ChequingAccount extends Account{
holder_ca;
}

While building  getting
Org.infinispan.protostream.annotations.ProtoSchemaBuilderExveption: The class java .time.ZonedDateTime must be instantiable using an accessible no-argument constructor
And java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected type kind:WILDCARD
How to generate schema for these

The following adapter should work:
@ProtoAdapter(ZonedDateTime.class)
public final class ZonedDateTimeAdapter {

   @ProtoFactory
   ZonedDateTime create(long epochSecond, String zoneId) {
      return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSecond), ZoneId.of(zoneId));
   }

   @ProtoField(number = 1, type = Type.UINT64)
   long getEpochSecond(ZonedDateTime zdt) {
      return zdt.toEpochSecond();
   }

   @ProtoField(number = 2, type = Type.STRING)
   String getZoneId(ZonedDateTime zdt) {
      return zdt.getZone().getId();
   }
}

